# How to delete rows from a table in database X, where the ID exists in Database Y

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I've got 2 mysql 5.7 databases hosted on the same server (we're migrating from 1 structure to another)

I want to delete all the rows from `database1.table_x` where the there is a corresponding row in `database2.table_y`

The column which contains the data to match on is called `code`

I'm able to do a `SELECT` which returns everything that is expected - this is effectively the set of data I want to delete.

An example select would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `database1`.`table_x` 
WHERE `code` NOT IN (SELECT `code` 
                     FROM `database2`.`table_y`);
```

This works and it returns 5 rows within 138ms.

--

However, If I change the `SELECT` to a `DELETE` e.g.

```
DELETE
FROM `database1`.`table_x` 
WHERE `code` NOT IN (SELECT `code` 
                     FROM `database2`.`table_y`);
```

The query seems to hang - there are no errors returned, so I have to manually cancel the query after about 3 minutes.

--

Could anyone advise the most efficient/fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: are these two tables in two different databases ?

Comment: Yes different databases but both on the same host

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Try this: 

`DELETE FROM first_database.table_a 
LEFT JOIN second_database.table_b ON second_database.table_b.code = first_database.table_a.code
WHERE second_database.table_b.code IS NULL;`

Comment: Instead of `NOT IN` you could try a `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below it will work

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE `code` NOT IN (      

        select * from 
         (
          SELECT `code` FROM `second_database`.`table_b`        
         ) as t

     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
 DELETE a 
 FROM first_database.table_a AS a 
 LEFT JOIN second_database.table_b AS b ON b.code = a.code 
 WHERE b.code IS NULL;
```